# Friend classes in the same namespace

Tags: c++, friend-class

I was programming Vulkan based renderer but unfortunately this error appeared:
**'Azazel::Instance::~Instance': cannot access private member declared in class 'Azazel::Instance'**
It gives me a headache. I tried to predeclare Azazel_Menager class at start of my namespace,
but it did not work as well so I changed:

`friend class Azazel_Menager;`

to:

`friend class Azazel::Azazel_Menager;`

well it did not do the trick as well. So here I'm asking for your help.
maybe you will see something I did not.

Azazel_Menager:

```
#pragma once
#include "Engine/Core/UsingTypes.h"
namespace Azazel
{
    class Instance;
    class PhysicalDevice;

    class Azazel_Menager
    {
    public:
        static void CreateInstance();
        static void RetrieveAndSetPhysicalDevice();
    private:
        static Ref<Instance> s_Instance;
        static Ref<PhysicalDevice> s_PhysicalDevice;
    };
}
```

Instance.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <VulkanSDK/include/vulkan/vulkan.hpp>
namespace Azazel
{
    class Azazel_Menager;
    class Instance
    {
        friend class Azazel::Azazel_Menager;
    private:
        Instance();
        ~Instance();
    public:
        vk::UniqueInstance m_Instance;
        VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT m_callback;
    };
}
```

Ref = std::shared_ptr

Comment: Please read about the [mcve]. (All the Vulkan stuff is irrelevant to the issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You probably use constructor/destructor outside of `Azazel_Menager` (as in `std::make_shared` or in default `Deleter`).

You have to use them exclusively in `Azazel_Menager`, as:

```
void Azazel_Menager::CreateInstance()
{
    s_Instance = std::shared_ptr<Azazel::Instance>{new Azazel::Instance{},
                                                   [](auto* p){ delete p; }};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yr3K3Yhqn)

Comment: Thanks that worked! But i debugged it a bit and noticed that i never call destructor of instance now. Should i make now a new function for it or what ?

Comment: From given code, destructor should be called when global are destroyed (*after* `main`).

Comment: well that is not something what i really wanted. Is it possible to call the destructor in idk static class Azazel_Menager in maybe new function like shutdown ?

Comment: You can reset the `std::shared_ptr` manually.

Comment: ok thanks for help i will do it like this i guess